# Toggle .click() method

Tags: jquery

My following click does not toggle. I don't want to use `.toggle()` method. I am using jquery 1.4.1

```
 $("#e_tooth_pk1").click(function () {
        $(this).css({ "background": "url(/DesktopModules/DMS/DMS.PatientEChart/images/line.gif) repeat-x scroll 0 19px transparent", "border": "1px solid #000", "-moz-box-sizing": "border-box" })
        $("#hid_tooth1").val("e_tooth1");
    }, function () {
        $(this).css({ "background-color": "transparent", "background": "none", "border": "none" })
        $("#hid_tooth1").val("0");
    });
```

Comment: "I am using jquery 1.4.1" -- please upgrade. Ideally, to 1.10 (+ Migrate plugin)

Comment: @JanDvorak Does the above function does not suuport jquery 1.4.1.

Comment: More importantly, [`$().delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) was added in 1.4.2, [`$().live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was officially deprecated in 1.7, and [`$().on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (which combines `bind` and `delegate`) didn't exist until 1.7. Until 1.4.2, there was no reasonable way to perform event delegation. 1.4 -> 1.5 is fully compatible, 1.5 -> 1.6 changes some rarely-used features that didn't make sense anyways, 1.6 -> 1.7 -> 1.8 are fully compatible, 1.8 -> 1.9 is mostly clean up that removes most deprecated functions. 1.9 -> 1.10 seems to mostly bugfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally find `css` kinda clunky to put so many styles in one setup.. so I'd suggest using classes to store your styles and manipulate them using `addClass`, `removeClass`, and `hasClass` instead of doing this. (just saying)

```
.line {
    background : url(/DesktopModules/DMS/DMS.PatientEChart/images/line.gif) repeat-x scroll 0 19px transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.no-line {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: none;
    border: none
}
```

Your JS code would look like this :

```
$("#e_tooth_pk1").click(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('no-line');
    if ($this.hasClass("no-line")) {
      //  $this.removeClass("no-line").addClass("line");
        $("#hid_tooth1").val("e_tooth1");
    } else {
      //  $this.removeClass("line").addClass("no-line");
        $("#hid_tooth1").val("0");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hBeCU/

Comment: or you can use  `.toggleClass()`

Comment: @Pumpkinpro i put it this way cos OP is changing some textbox value after this :)

Answer (score 5):

you could do:

```
var clicked = "first";
$("#e_tooth_pk1").click(function () {
    if( clicked == "first" ) {
        $(this).css({ "background": "url(/DesktopModules/DMS/DMS.PatientEChart/images/line.gif) repeat-x scroll 0 19px transparent", "border": "1px solid #000", "-moz-box-sizing": "border-box" });
        $("#hid_tooth1").val("e_tooth1");
        clicked = "second";
    }
    else if(clicked == "second") {
       $(this).css({ "background-color": "transparent", "background": "none", "border": "none" });
       $("#hid_tooth1").val("0");
       clicked = "first";
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you return `clicked`?